# Can't use plotly.express with Jupyter Notebook: graphs won't show

Tags: plot, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter, plotly-python

I tried to create graphs using plotly express as indicated in a Youtube tutorial (link below) and it won't work. Looked everywhere to see the reason but can't seem to find a solution so my last resort is to post here after wasting a good amount of time on this silly problem... hope someone can help, otherwise, I won't be able to use Jupyter Notebooks which I really wanted to, and will have to just stick to Visual Studio which is working fine with plotly.express.

The link to the tutorial is this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8RgYJ0ztN0)

The link to the notebook and data is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XzmUBoOfp4bsH38oBSTiVXFVuBIzagVA):

The code I am including it below too:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('MARKETING MIX MODELING YT - SAMPLE RAW DATA.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
fig = px.line(df, x= 'Date', y='FB' )
fig.show()
```

Comment: are you using the latest version of `plotly` in google colab?

Comment: Hi, I am using jupyter notebooks locally, and I have installed the latest version of plotly (5.14.0).

Comment: have you gone through the steps in the documentation [here](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#jupyter-notebook-support)?

Comment: So you don't get an error, but the plot just shows as empty white space? And your comment above says you have installed locally the latest version of plotly but you don't specify how or where. Often times issues like this are caused by installing locally but not to the same place Jupyter is using. You have provided very little information on your own system here. So advising you us hard. Are you using Anaconda / conda as your package manager? Or are those not involved at all? If you are just trying to learn, sometimes it is easier to use a session online where things work already instead of...

Comment: <continued> of battling environment or faulty/incomplete installation issues that may have been caused on your local system. I can suggest going [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder) and pressing 'launch binder'. Then in the session that comes up, click on the 'Jupyter' logo. Now, you'll be on the dashboard and you can upload your file. If you prefer drag-and-drop, change `tree` at the end of the URL to `lab`. In JupyterLab,  you can try drag-and-drop in your notebook and csv file from your local machine into the file navigation panel on the left side to upload them ...

Comment: <continued> to the remote machine. If you find JupyterLab being weird, you can switch back to the classic mode from under JupyterLab's 'Help' menu. Sometimes one or the other will work best but where I sent you, both Jupyter interfaces should be working properly in conjunction with Plotly.